# Javascript application - leak memory

Tags: javascript, jquery

I developed a client side application and unfortunately I suspect memory leaks.
The application has a lot of private clone objects, and at the end of each function I dispose the objects by set them to null.  (`foo = null;`)

My question is, how should I dispose of the objects?
Is it enough to use `foo = null`?

Also, are there any tools that can help me identify the problem?

**SOLUTION**

finally my problem caused of a wrong use of the jquery progress bar

```
        function updateProgressBar() {
        if (!handle) //by adding this, the problem solved. 
            return;
        jQuery("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: ++pct
        });
        if (pct >= 100) {
            clearInterval(handle);
            pct = 0;
            setInterval("updateProgressBar()", 300);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you suspect a memory leak?

Comment: I observe the the process of the browser and will I access the application, after a minute or two the memory increasing dramatically and in the end I am getting a message from the browser which says "Low memory". Maybe I use wrong word by "suspected". The correct is that I am sure :)

Comment: Check out the chrome developer tools. There's a heap snapshot that will show you how much memory you're consuming at x time and will let you go through your entire chain.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what browsers you're seeing this in.

Comment: firefox and chrome. Finally was a wrong use of jquery progrssBar(). But through this task, I learn how to identify memory leaks :)

Answer (score 3):

The main reason for memory leaks in a browser is when you have cyclical links between DOM and JavaScript objects. Mostly happens when orphaned DOM nodes still refer to event handlers or other JS objects. http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/heap-profiling-dom-leaks.html

Chrome developer tools lets you look at the heap and examine elements that are still lying in memory but are not through the "Heap Profiler"  used http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/08/finding-memory-leaks.html

But to address the actual answer, setting a property to null is enough to break cyclical references and should fix memory leaks.

Comment: the second url you suggested me is great. Thanks a lot

Comment: Unfortunately, the second link refers to a user with a Mac. Anything a user does with a Mac should be discarded. Silly Mac, tricks are for kids. </silly>

Comment: @ShadowScripter Didn't get your humor :p

Answer (score 0):

May it be a problem with closures? You should try the methods that the current browsers provide, like [Speed Tracer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl#detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl) for Chrome.

In any case, a snippet of the code you are using would be useful to try to identify the problem.